# "Pulling" variables from the console instead of "pushing"

Tags: javascript, browser, console, console.log

Is there a way to read variable values while in the console by "pulling" instead of "pushing"?

For example, say, I have somewhere in my JS:

```
var a = "foo";
```

Can I "pull" the value of `a` from the console by typing *in the console* something like

```
$.a
```

or

```
$.this.a
```

By "pushing" I mean writing something like this in the JS:

```
console.log(a);
```

That is what I **do not** wish to do.

Comment: Short answer: not really. Long answer: There is no direct way of doing this, though there are some libraries around that simulate this for you. When I googled this I got tons of resources so I suggest you do this yourself and follow one of those guides.

Comment: if all you want to do is log it...you don't need to type `console.log` right in the console... just put the variable name and run that. Not really clear how you are trying to use this

Comment: @Glubus: I did google it. And got nothing. (Which is why I posted here.) What search term/s / string/s did you use?

Comment: In pretty much every console, you can assign variables: `window.my_vars = {}; my_vars.a = "foo";`
Then just change your code to reference `my_vars.a`.

Comment: @JayDansand: You are referring to putting that in the JS correct? That's what I'm calling "pushing." Which is what I'm **not** trying to do. I'm seeking a "pull" method only. i.e., only using the console exclusively with no preparation in the JS.

Comment: So, you have JS running which you cannot modify, and you want to inject values into the variables using the console? Because if you can modify the JS, it's simple to open it up. Otherwise you'll need to use your browsers debugger (which is still possible and simple).

Comment: @JayDansand: *Otherwise you'll need to use your browsers debugger (which is still possible and simple).* Could you please post an answer that describes how to do that?

Comment: @Mowzer, I've added an answer with relevant links, and tried to summarize the discussion above so that other people with different needs may find it useful. I don't have space to recreate debugger documentation (hence the links), but the Chrome/Firefox docs will give you general concepts that apply fairly universally across browsers (the debuggers are all fairly similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the variable is in the global scope or some object in the global scope (e.g. `window`) has a reference to it**, then you can read/modify it from the console by simple assignment/reference; just type `MyGlobal` or `MyGlobal = "foo"` into the console and execute it. In the first case, it'll print the current value, and in the latter it will modify the value. If the variable is only locally-scoped (i.e. it is just defined inside a particular function: `function() { var a = "foo"; ...}`), then the console cannot access/alter it without using the script debugger (see bottom of this answer) or modifying the script (see below).

**If the variable isn't in the global scope or referenced by a global object, but you can edit the script**, you can easily open it up to the console. Instead of `var a = "foo"`, do something like `window.myOptions = {a: "foo"}`. Then from the console, you can execute `window.myOptions.a` to read or `window.myOptions.a = "bar"` to set the value.

**If you need to read/modify the values of local variables in a script and you do not have access to change the actual script**, you can use your browser's script debugger.

- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger
- Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

An easy method is to set a breakpoint at the variable you want to read/change (usually by clicking your mouse on the line number in the script debugging window; see links above for details) and then, when the script executes, it will pause when that line runs. Hovering over the variable with your mouse, or reading the info panes on the right (depending on debugger and window configuration) will show you the currently value. It also gives you a chance to modify the variable's value. You can set breakpoints at a function definition too, to read/change the parameters given to the function.

It's possible in Safari, IE/Edge, Firefox, and Chrome (basically any modern browser with good debugger tools). Firefox has a handy step-by-step guide called "Examine, modify, and watch variables": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Examine,_modify,_and_watch_variables